# Is Servic Fabric Appropriate for Simple Background Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric

We have a bunch of Windows Services. We need to be able to continue to deploy our code as Windows service on premise, but would like to deploy to Azure where appropriate. The goal is to manage less infrastructure. I'm not keen on deploying dozens of bits an pieces as Azure Functions, but not entirely opposed to it either. Azure Batch / Webjobs are also another option. However, the long term goal is to move all of our services over to an orchestration server like Service Fabric so that all the services can be deployed and orchestrated from the one place. This is mainly a deployment consideration.

We will break the existing C# code in to .NET Core class libraries and reference them from either Service Fabric hosted in Azure, on-premise Service Fabric, or on-premise Windows Service. Is Service Fabric an appropriate choice? Or, is there a strong reason to run background jobs as Azure Batch / Functions / Webjobs?

This is Microsoft's diagram from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree):
[image]

The answer to the question is that we don't really *need* full fledged orchestration right now, but it will become more important moving in to future. I have to balance being able to deploy all our code in one hit with the ease of *ad hoc* deployment that Azure Functions offer.

Comment: if you porting your code to .NET Core anyway, can't you run it in containers then? possibly even Linux containers. Then might be able to use AKS

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to run it on Kubernetes. What would the advantage of Kubernetes over Service Fabric be?

Answer (score 1):

(Stateful) Services can be an excellent way to run background jobs. They offer the `RunAsync` [entry point,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.runtime.statefulservicebase.runasync?view=azure-dotnet) in which you can run your job, check (and store) progress. SF really shines when multiple services collaborate on tasks, offering SF Remoting as a communication channel, with built-in retry support.

You can choose to containerize your software, which would free you from platform lock-in, but prevent you from using some [platform features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-services-inside-containers).

By automating delivery of services (CI/CD), you can deploy to any platform you choose. This is not something that is specific to SF.

Comment: We current use Fluent Scheduler for scheduling tasks. I basically find this pretty good. But, the Service Fabric entry point model seems a bit different. They seem to recommend putting a Task.Delay in a loop so scheduling becomes something different. Is there any guidance around on how to implement configurable scheduling and so on?

Comment: It's likely you can just run your existing code and framework inside a Service. For example, start the scheduler in `RunAsync` (`JobManager.Initialize(new MyRegistry())`) and keep checking the passed `CancellationToken`, when it gets set you stop the scheduler (`JobManager.StopAndBlock();`) on that instance.

Comment: I suppose it's possible but it seems silly that the app is structured this way

Comment: Because on the one hand Fluent Scheduler is scheduling the jobs, and on the other hand there is a process that is stuck in an infinite loop and calling delay to just keep the thread running.

Comment: Oh, I see. Feel free to let `RunAsync` complete/return, there's no requirement to use this approach, nor to implement it. Exiting RunAsync doesn't influence the service life-cycle (not exiting it does extend the life-cycle). You can also override `OnOpenAsync` and `OnCloseAsync` to manage the `JobManager`.

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by "not exiting it does extend the life-cycle" ?

Comment: if you keep the thread that runs RunAsync occupied forever (e.g. `while (true)` and ignore the cancellation token, your service will keep running even though the runtime wants to stop it.

Comment: I'm so confused. If I let the loop exit, will the service stop?

Comment: No, only if the cancellation token is cancelled. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle)..